# Twisted $\frac{m k}{\ell k}$ Calabi-Yau does not imply twisted $\frac{m}{\ell}$ Calabi-Yau in general

Tags: rt.representation-theory

[Herschend and Iyama](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.3510v2.pdf) p.2.: Let $K$ be a field and $\Lambda$ a finite-dimensional $K$-algebra of finite global dimension. For each $K$-algebra endomorphism $\phi$ of $\Lambda$, we define an endofunctor of $\mathcal{D}$ by
$$
\phi^{*}:=\Lambda_{\phi} \stackrel{\mathrm{L}}{\otimes}_{\Lambda}-: \mathcal{D} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}
$$
where we denote by $\Lambda_{\phi}$ the $\Lambda \otimes_{K} \Lambda^{\text {op}}$-module such that the right action is given by $a \cdot b:=a \phi(b)$.

Definition 0.3. We say that $\Lambda$ is **twisted fractionally CY** (or twisted $\frac{m}{\ell}$-CY) if there exists an isomorphism
$$
\nu^{\ell} \simeq[m] \circ \phi^{*}
$$
of functors for some integers $\ell \neq 0$ and $m$ and a $K$-algebra endomorphism $\phi$ of $\Lambda$. Then $\phi$ must be an automorphism since $\nu$ is an autofunctor. When $\phi=\mathrm{id}$, we say that $\Lambda$ is fractionally CY(or $\frac{m}{\ell}$-CY).

Notice that (twisted) $\frac{m}{\ell}$-CY algebras are also (twisted) $\frac{m k}{\ell k}$-CY for any $k \neq 0$. **The converse does not hold in general**, but the Calabi-Yau dimension is unique as a rational number.

---

Could you please explain why the converse does not hold in general? And when does it hold? Thank you:)